# Ansible docker module missing CP command?

Tags: docker, ansible, cp, docker-cp

The docker client offers the **cp** sub-command as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/), which is very handy when one needs to copy a file into a container (note: this is somewhat analogous to Dockerfile ADD instruction in image building). In Docker 1.8 the **cp** command has been even expanded a bit.

However, reading the [Ansible docker module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html), it appears that this is missing? Here are my 2 questions:

1. Did I misunderstand the Ansible documentation?
2. if Ansible is missing the cp thing, has anyone found a workaround? I can think of something like using Ansible **copy module**  to transport the files to the remote machine first, and then run there the native docker client with **cp**, but ideally Ansible's docker module would have done this in a single shot as part of the docker module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the synchronize command ~ examples provided in this link:

http://opensolitude.com/2015/05/26/building-docker-images-with-ansible.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to "synchronize". That's sounds better than using " copy" as my workaround suggested. I filed request with ansible to extend the docket module, but for now this is the best we have...

Answer (score 2):

Using ansible `shell` module helped:

```
  - name: copy db dump to localhost
    ansible.builtin.shell: docker cp container:/tmp/dump.sql /tmp/dump.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You didn't. Ansible's docker module does not support copying files or folders from a container.
2. There is no simple way to do so. I mean you need a hack. Off the top of my head you can play with '-' argument for docker `cp` option.

However from my point of view if you wish to copy something into a container you're probably doing something wrong. Containers should be ephemeral.

Comment: There are lots of valid reasons to copy files into and out of containers, which is why docker itself has the functionality and is expanding it.

Comment: Probably,  however from my experiance such cases mean a bad design

Comment: Agreed on the bad design but the most useful related case is using ansible to copy a file into a docker named volume.

Comment: I would disagree on that it categorically means a bad design. For example I use NiFi in container and need to copy DB drivers (SAP ASE) into there. I could do mount, but it feels even more ugly.